# How to make relationship array type foreign_key in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I am storing data in database as array which is foreign key of another table.
So, when I am trying to fetch that array id normal laravel one to one retationship it's show empty.
My workout code is below:-

In controller:-

```
$data =  Category::with('type')->all();
```

In Category Model:-

```
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Types','id','category');
```

In Types Model:-

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
```

Stored data in type

```
|| id || name || category ||
    3    test     ["5","6"]
```

From these table I just want to fetch data of type name **test** having category id 5,6.

I feel grateful helpful to someone who give the better idea and logic to solve this issue. Thank you!!!

Comment: If this is stored as string `["5","6"]` then it is wrong data structure.

Comment: To many problems with your concept. Database does not designed in proper way. There are mistakes inside Models. Search the internet for a good tutorial about `Laravel Eloquent Relationship`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your view and word. So to store integer type in an array group data type integer does not work

Comment: if array be [5,6], then how to relate id in eloquent model for id

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some modification

first of first: if your types belong to more than one category then create a `pivot` table named `category_type` containing 
`category_id` AND `type_id` fields

So in your **Category** model

```
class Category extends Model
{
   public function types()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
   }
}
```

Then:

```
$data =  Category::with('types')->all();
```